# I have a macro to refresh all pivot tables in my workbook, I need to add code to remove (blanks)'s

Tags: vba, excel, pivot

I have a workbook with multiple pivot tables throughout. I have found some code that works for refreshing all of my pivot tables at once (assigned to a button). But in order for the rest of my calculations to work, I currently have to go to each table and deselect (blank) from the Row Labels filter.

I've tried many options to add code that will also filter out the blanks, but can't seem to get the syntax right.

Here's what I'm currently using to refresh all of my pivot tables; what do I need to add to filter the blanks as well?

```
Sub RefreshAllPivotTables()
    Dim PT As PivotTable
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each PT In WS.PivotTables
            PT.RefreshTable
        Next PT
    Next WS
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. Basically just added the loop through each of the Pivot Fields

```
Sub RefreshAllPivotTables()

Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim PF As PivotField

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each PT In WS.PivotTables
            PT.RefreshTable
            For Each PF In PT.PivotFields
                On Error Resume Next
                PF.PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
            Next PF
        Next PT
    Next WS
End Sub
```

Comment: If you deem this as the answer, please mark as Answered so people would still think you are trying to solve

Comment: Hey thanks for your help! I'm still getting an error though. It works perfectly for the first pivot table, but then I get an error: "Run-time error '1004': Method 'PivotItems' of object 'PivotField' failed".

I tried to search for a solution, but haven't been able to figure it out. One person suggested using this code to clear the pivot cache. It didn't cause any new problems, but didn't solve my issue either:

I also tried changing the data source to use R1C1 notation.

Comment: Is there a “(blank)” in the second pivot table? If not then add the Error catch (see edit) if there are no blanks in the pivot table the macro can’t hide them since they don’t exist. If you catch the Error then it will ignore those pivot tables without the blank value

Comment: If this was the correct answer, please mark as answered so other users will know this is closed

Comment: That did it. Thanks for the help!